# Xcode/Objective-C implementing a players turn toggle

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm new to the whole VCM programming structure and more specifically to objective-c.

Right now i'm working on an iOS app that is like the game "connect 4." This Xcode project is my practice project that i've been using to play around/learn how to make iOS apps so there are several files and lots of commented out code, so Ill try my best to provide the necessary content from my project.

---

### App State:

Right now I have a 10x10 grid of blue square/buttons. I'm still in the early stages of implementing the functionality of the game. Rather than making each square its own button, I created 10 frames and 10 buttons. Each row is a single  button, which is broken up into 10 squares.

I currently have the squares change their color to red and become disabled once clicked. If I click multiple times.. the squares turn red when pressed. Heres a screenshot example run: [image]

---

### What Im wanting to do:

I want to build off of what I have, but not exactly sure how to keep track of which "players turn" it is. For example.. I want the first clicked square to turn red, representing player1's move. I want the second click to turn the button, say green, representing player2's move.. then the next move will be player 1's move.

I know Ill have to make sure the button is/was ENABLED and valid before switching which players turn it is.

---

How should I go about doing this? This is more of a general question, but I'll provide needed code snippets if necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your .h file add an integer (variable)

```
int Turn = 1;
```

In your .m file you can do:

```
if(Turn == 1)
{
    // Player one is playing
    Turn = 2;
}

else if(Turn == 2)
{
    // Player two is playing
    Turn = 1;
}
```